# Change background using scikit-image?

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

Is it possible to change the background of this image using scikit-image?
I am not familiar with open-cv but little with scikit-image. I would like to know which modules/functions available in scikit-image are useful for this purpose.
[How do I remove the background from this kind of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313667/how-do-i-remove-the-background-from-this-kind-of-image)
May I ask- How you would do?

Comment: I never used scikit-image, but for such task one of possible solutions will be Active Contours/Snakes. I see PR with such algo in scikit-image, https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/1691

Comment: Which kind of image? You only linked a post with an actual solution. All the functions in that post have a similar one in scikits-image. Which exactly is your question?

Comment: @imaluengo I'm interested in the same image as posted in that link, but using scikits-image. I could not imagine relevant functions in scikits-image.

Comment: `imread` is in the `skimage.io` package. `dilate` and `erode` are in `skimage.morphology`. `gaussianBlur` is in `scipy.ndimage`. Contour finding works differently in skimage, but you can find an example [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_contours.html). The other operations are numpy or standard python functions. My question is, if that works for you, why would you like to translate it to another python library? Both OpenCV (for python) and Scikits-image use numpy, but they don't have exactly the same functions. What you could do is to try some different approach.

Comment: Try [this](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/tutorial_segmentation.html) or [this](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_coins_segmentation.html) guides, they might give you some insight for different approaches.