# Using opencv to plot a path in a maze via Pi camera

Tags: python, opencv, maze, watershed

So I was originally going to use watershed and fumble my way through. I found a maze solver on git that I'm looking to understand better, and make work for a picamera image
  https://github.com/raincrash/image_processing/blob/master/maze_solver/maze_solver.py

when I use the image he supplies it works, but when I swap the image out for one that I took with the pi, all I get is a black screen when at the point it looks to find the contour.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

i = cv2.imread('img.jpg')

cv2.imshow("Original", i)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Convert to binary
# Find the contour, draw
# Make a mask and Dilate
# Then, Erode
# Find the difference
# Get the new mask (Solution)
# Merge the images and show

gray_scale = cv2.cvtColor(i, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_scale, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

cv2.imshow("first thresh", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(thresh, contours, 0, (255, 255, 255), -1)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(thresh, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

dilate_mask = np.ones((19, 19), np.uint8)
dilate_result = cv2.dilate(thresh, dilate_mask, iterations = 1)

cv2.imshow("dilate", dilate_result)
cv2.waitKey(0)

erosion_result = cv2.erode(dilate_result, dilate_mask, iterations = 1)

cv2.imshow("erosion", erosion_result)
cv2.waitKey(0)

difference = cv2.absdiff(dilate_result, erosion_result)

cv2.imshow("difference", difference)
cv2.waitKey(0)

b, g, r = cv2.split(i)
mask = difference
result_mask_inverse = cv2.bitwise_not(difference)
r = cv2.bitwise_and(r, r, mask = result_mask_inverse)
g = cv2.bitwise_and(g, g, mask = result_mask_inverse)


result = cv2.merge((b, g, r))
cv2.imshow('solved maze', result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destoyAllWindows()
```

here's the image I'm using

Pi maze

[image]

what am I missing? shouldn't the `findCountor` function look for the edges? are the edges too jagged for it to find?

Comment: Can you also add a picture that shows (maybe approximately) the final result? In the meanwhile, check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43545744/4618605

Comment: hi, thanks for getting back to me. some family stuff has come up so I'm putting this attempt on hold for a week.  I  do appreciate you getting back to me.