# OpenCV : Remove background of an image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am using Opencv and python to detect shapes and then crop them. I have succeeded to do that, however now I am trying to take the cropped images and remove  their backgrounds.

The image has a circle inside and surrounded by gray color. (***It can be gray or can be even more than one color***).

[image: Croped Image]

How can I remove the colors surrounding the circle border (which is black) - we can convert the gray color to black - as the border color or even remove it at all and make that transparent.

***The result image should contain only the circle.***

Comment: This solved answer seems quite close https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294109/remove-background-of-the-image-using-opencv-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least in for this image, there is no need to detect the circle use `houghCircle)`.  I think `threshold` it and `find the inner contour` , then `make mask` and `do bitwise-op` is OK!

[image]

My steps:

> (1) Read and convert to gray
>
> (2) findContours
>
> (3) find contour that smaller, create a mask
>
> (4) do `bitwise_and` to `crop`

---

Here is my result:

[image]

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018.01.20 20:58:12 CST
# 2018.01.20 21:24:29 CST
import cv2
import numpy as np

## (1) Read
img = cv2.imread("img04.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

## (2) Threshold
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

## (3) Find the min-area contour
_cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
for cnt in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 100:
        break

## (4) Create mask and do bitwise-op
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt],-1, 255, -1)
dst = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

## Save it
cv2.imwrite("dst.png", dst)
```

Comment: I am trying since 2 days. Did not succeed. Need help :-( A code can help so I can follow and learn from

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this works only if the background is gray. I have tested it with gray background and it works fine, however if the background has more colorful objects so this does not work.- See images attached links.
I am new to all of this image processing and openCV .. So be patient with me please 

:-)
In my questions i wrote: "The image has a circle inside and surrounded by gray color. (It can be gray or can be even more than one color)."


See the images please here: 

https://imgur.com/lQ0XQ8L

https://imgur.com/UaYcH8f

Comment: Read the first line of my answer: `At least for this image ...`

Comment: You are right.

So if I use the houghCircle which we used for cropping the latest circle image (an image contains the main circle and some more colors on the gray background outside of the circle area) and then mask it will help?

Can you give hints and tips here?

Comment: To be honest, I will not provide any advice any more, unless your question is clear enough, with all the explicit examples.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384516/python-opencv-cropping-images-and-isolating-specific-objects

Hope this is clear.

Comment: please me help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216402/how-to-improve-image-segmentation-using-the-watershed/61263538?noredirect=1#comment108440035_61263538 i need solved this