# How to make black outside of exact shape of cv2.polylines?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using cv2.MSER_create to find stable regions of an image. After I get hulls and put cv2.polylines on the image. Question: How can I make outside of the polylines black as shown below?

[Example of before and after filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BB1k.jpg)

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, numb, figsize=(12,2.5))
for i in range(numb):
    vis_copy = vis.copy()
    mser = cv2.MSER_create(_min_area = min_a, _max_area=max_a)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(vis_copy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_blur = gray#cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)

    regions, _ = mser.detectRegions(gray_blur)
    c = sorted(regions, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True) 
    hulls = [cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1,1,2)) for p in c]
    cv2.polylines(vis_copy, hulls, 1, (0, 255, 0))
    axes[i].imshow(vis_copy)
    axes[i].set_title('Min_a =' +  str(min_a) )
    axes[i].set_xticks([])
    axes[i].set_yticks([])    
    min_a = min_a + step_a
```

Comment: Would this answer be relevant? I dont have openCV on my machine so unable to test: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29314286/2102114

Comment: Thank you, that's good example