# Get boundary from canny edges and remove the background of an image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to remove the background of an image that im trying to train a neural network with. I've had little luck using the method described here ([How do I remove the background from this kind of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313667/how-do-i-remove-the-background-from-this-kind-of-image)), but I have been able to use the Canny Edge Detector to get a semi-good "boundary" of the object in my image. Heres my code I'm running

```
import cv2 as cv, sys, numpy as np, PIL.Image, matplotlib.pylab as plt

# read command-line arguments
filename = '/Users/colew/Desktop/Good_Cups_Frames/frame_IMG_2057.MOV_0.jpg'

img = cv.imread(filename,0)
edges = cv.Canny(img,25,200)
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.savefig("pic")
plt.show()
```

and the resulting image(s) we get are

[image]

So what I'm looking for exactly is a way for me to get the boundaries of the canny edges and then from there, crop the original image around these boundaries. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove the background and extract the object. Instead of using Canny, here's an alternative approach. Since you didn't provide an original image, I screenshotted your image to use as input. In general, there are several ways to obtain a binary image for boundary extraction. They include regular thresholding, Otsu's thresholding, Adaptive thresholding, and Canny edge detection. In this case, Otsu's is probably the best since there is background noise

[image]

---

First we convert the image to grayscale then perform Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image

[image]

There are unwanted sections so to remove them, we perform a morph open to separate the joints

[image]

Now that the joints are separated, we find contours and filter using contour area. We extract the largest contour which represents the desired object then draw this contour onto a mask

[image]

We're almost there but there are imperfections so we morph close to fill the holes

[image]

Next we bitwise-and with the original image

[image]

Finally to get the desired result, we color in all black pixels on the mask to white

[image]

From here you could use Numpy slicing to extract the ROI but I'm not completely sure what you were trying to do. I'll leave that up to you

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("1.png")
original = image.copy()
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=3)

cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
    break

close = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=4)
close = cv2.cvtColor(close, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(original, original, mask=close)
result[close==0] = (255,255,255)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. Is there some way to get a little more of the background gone, when I run it I get a little bit, im assuming because the glare of the image is so close to the color of the background

Comment: You can experiment with the kernel size and the number of iterations. Increasing the kernel size and number of iterations will remove more and will result in a smaller mask